# Involved Probability Question

Tags: probability

I'm trying to review probability, but am having trouble with more complex problems. For example:

Given a jar with $n_1$ red marbles, $n_2$ blue marbles, and $n_3$ green marbles, what is the probability that if we grab a handful $h$ of marbles, we will have chosen a handful where we have $m$ of one color and $(h-m)/2$ of each of the other two colors.

I feel the denominator of the expression is $n_i+n_2+_n3 \choose h$, but I'd appreciate some help on how to go about finding the numerator.

Comment: I would split it into three cases: The case where you grab $m$ of the reds, the case where you grab $m$ of the blue, and the case where you grab $m$ of the green.

Comment: The numerator for $m$ red balls should be $\binom{n_1}{m}\binom{n_2}{(h-m)/2}\binom{n_3}{(h-m)/2}$

Comment: Thanks for your tips. Am I correct in reasoning that the final expression be 

$n_1 \choose m$ $n_2 \choose (h-m)/2$ $n_3 \choose (h-m)/2$ + $n_2 \choose m$ $n_1 \choose (h-m)/2$ $n_3 \choose (h-m)/2$ + $n_3 \choose m$ $n_2 \choose (h-m)/2$ $n_1 \choose (h-m)/2$ 

over the denominator I provided above?

Comment: Yes thats what I got BUT there is one annoying details. You can't have $h=3m$ because then the events would not be disjoint.